# Replace UTF string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a data set which looks like this:

```
701 B STREET
SUITE C
SAN DIEGO,CA 92101
¥************CAR INFO******************
¥ZE CD-1337966
¥ZI CD-D515000 FOR MONTHLY RATES PLS CALL
¥AVIS MINI LEASE PLS CALL 800-524-9000 EXT 3034
¥CONTACT EMAIL CANDACE.GREER.AT.CENDANT.COM
¥ANY OTHER CAR COMPANY USED OTHER THAN THE ABOVE
¥WILL NOT REIMBURSED FOR THE COST OF INSURANCE
```

I want to replace the Yen symbol.

I tried this :

```
$data_result=str_replace(chr(0xC2).chr(0xA5),"",$data);
```

Still could not replace the expression.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Do you know in which encoding that data set is returned to PHP? Most likable are UTF-8, UTF-16 or some Ansi encoding, but the Yen symbol has a different code in every one of them.

Comment: why cant you replace the yen symbol literally

Comment: More likely you are interpreting the text in the wrong encoding and there isn't actually any ¥ character in there.

Comment: Not sure that the UTF-8 code I used is correctly used

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = '701 B STREET
SUITE C
SAN DIEGO,CA 92101
¥************CAR INFO******************
¥ZE CD-1337966
¥ZI CD-D515000 FOR MONTHLY RATES PLS CALL
¥AVIS MINI LEASE PLS CALL 800-524-9000 EXT 3034
¥CONTACT EMAIL CANDACE.GREER.AT.CENDANT.COM
¥ANY OTHER CAR COMPANY USED OTHER THAN THE ABOVE
¥WILL NOT REIMBURSED FOR THE COST OF INSURANCE';

$str = preg_replace('/¥/u', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

**output:**

```
701 B STREET
SUITE C
SAN DIEGO,CA 92101
************CAR INFO******************
ZE CD-1337966
ZI CD-D515000 FOR MONTHLY RATES PLS CALL
AVIS MINI LEASE PLS CALL 800-524-9000 EXT 3034
CONTACT EMAIL CANDACE.GREER.AT.CENDANT.COM
ANY OTHER CAR COMPANY USED OTHER THAN THE ABOVE
WILL NOT REIMBURSED FOR THE COST OF INSURANCE
```

Comment: if this is an accepted answer then I should kill myself :D

Comment: @aelor try `str_replace()` :D

Comment: The above answer replaces the whole line which has yen symbol with space

Comment: @user1986787: No, it doesn't.